# SceneKit PBR - multiply albedo

Tags: scenekit, texture-mapping, scnscene, pbr, scnmaterial

I need to multiply a bitmap on top of an albedo/diffuse. I’m using PBR shading.

Ex: apply a tattoo (bitmap) on top a skin (albedo/diffuse), multiplying so you can see the tattoo overlaying the skin.

Question: this tattoo (bitmap) should be a second albedo/diffuse? Or set as another material? If yes, what kind of material?

Thanks!